# Maximizing initiative

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

What non-magic item and non-spell options are available to characters for maximizing initiative?

Things I am thinking:

Race that boosts DEX
Certain classes like Scout or Swordsage
The Improved Initiative feat

What am I missing? Let's include splat books.

Comment: We don't do lists. If you have a character you're trying to optimise, please [edit] to include all your build details and restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [this](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?125732-3-x-X-stat-to-Y-bonus) a pretty good resource.  Though it is incomplete, as it only lists how to get ability modifiers.  Here's a quick screencap of the initiative section for you.  [image: This is a table of the relevant initiative modifiers]

Another good (and more thorough) resource can be found at   [Brilliant Gameologists](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=6000)  which should have the information you require.

Happy Optimizing!